# [Mac OS][Terminal] Setting custom prompt is not working

Tags: macos, terminal

I wanted to show the full path on OS X terminal / iTerm before the $ prompt. I tried the following steps:

1. Edit ~/.bash_profile and add the following line to show full path before the $ prompt.
   For example, as user@hostname:path/to/directory$

   `export PS1='\u@\H:\w$ '`
2. Save file and restart terminal or run source command

   `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

But, the value of `\u,\H` and `\w` and not getting replaced. Find the screenshot below:

[image]

Why is it happening like this?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you happen to be in `zsh` ? Can you run `echo $BASH_VERSION` ?

Comment: @Philippe yes. But then I have uninstalled zsh. `echo $BASH_VERSION` is not printing anything.

Comment: You may still in zsh, run `echo $ZSH_VERSION`

Comment: Yup. That was the issue. changed to bash and working fine now! Thanks.